# When I use Glide to load picture, there is a black area on this picture

Tags: android, image, android-glide

[image]

I'm loading it on a Recycler View, and every item is a picture of 9 grid.3x3.The whole is a square.An item is a square.The source image itself is not have the black region, just showing up. 
This is my Glide method:

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .dontTransform()
                .dontAnimate();
        Glide.with(context).load(url)
                .apply(options)
                .into(view);
```

it's simple, what's should I do to solve this？

[image]

Comment: The image is very small. The question is quite unspecific. What is a miwagi? Please, rephrase your question in a more specific, clear way. Also, you should post some relevant code, like the layout you used (in this case the relevant item is the ImageView, and the issue is very likely to be related to android:scaleType having a wrong value).

Comment: Please edit your question and improve it by adding at least the code where you want to have this picture. The image is so small anyway.

Comment: Yes, I need to add some information to illustrate my problem. I'm sorry